# How can I set a default using a String instead of a plist in Firebase Remote Config?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-remote-config

I'm trying to define a default value for my Firebase Remote Config setup.

But I'm not using a plist and have no intention to, since I already have everything setup and working well with Strings (via a Struct) for my constants.

With a plist, the syntax is:

`remoteConfig.setDefaultsFromPlistFileName("RemoteConfigDefaults")`

But, is there a way to define the default value using a String?

In other words, I have this value, which is just a String:

`Constants.URLs.FeedFallback = "https://www.mywebsite.com/stuff/"`

I just want to pass that in to seDefaults() somehow.  Is this possible?  What is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use the `FIRRemoteConfig.remoteConfig().setDefaults()` method, which allows you to supply an NSDictionary instead of a plist file. (In Swift you'll be using dictionary of type `[String: NSObject]`)

Just load up your dictionary with your keys and constants, and you should be all set.